# CSS Slider is overlaying Mobile-Nav but it's still clickable

Tags: html, css, bxslider

I have a Navigation-Bar and beneath there is a Slider (bxslider Plugin).
In the Navigation-Bar there is a navigation for mobile user and when it will be clicked, it appears.

When I'm clicking it, the navigation appears but not over the Slider. It seems that the Slider is overlaying the Mobile-Navigation but it is still clickable. When I'm clicking at the Mobile-Navigation at the Slider the Navigation is reacting.

This error appears on a Samsung Tablet with Google Chrome and in Safari on a iPad.

[Screenshot from iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l7nh.png)

```
#navigation {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:50000;
    background:rgb(255,255,255);
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    box-shadow:grey 0px 1px 2px;
}

#mmenu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:-350px;
    width:250px;
    height:100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #25438d 0%, #0555a4 80%);
    z-index:15;
    box-shadow:2px 0 8px black;
    transition: right 0.2s ease-out;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

#mmenu-btn {
    position:relative;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    top:-7px;
    border-radius:50px;
    z-index:1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #25438d 0%, #0555a4 80%);
}

#slider {
    position:relative;
    max-height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I've tried to set the #Slider z-index to -1 but nothing changes.
Where is the error? Is there a special-case because Tablets?

If you need further details, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: It's not easy to try and overlay bxSlider with z-index, instead, you might want to try hiding the slider when you click the navbar. If this interests you, I can help, but I'll need the JS/jQuery,and HTML that's relevant to the navbar and bxSlider.

Comment: I don't want to hide the slider. The Navigation should be visible above the Slider ;)